# Filter layerlist in snapping dock of QGIS3 to show only layers selected in the layer-dock (TOC)

Tags: qgis-3, snapping, pyqgis-3, pyqt5

I would like to filter the layerlist in the "Snapping and Digitizing Options"-Dock so that only layers are shown which are selected in the TOC of the QGIS-Layer-Dock.

At the moment I use a workaround which searches the UI components like

```
self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'Snapping and Digitizing Options')
```

This solution seems a bit hacky to me so I like to ask if someone has a better idea to filter the layerlist in the Snapping-Dock?

[image]

The goal is to filter 5 or 10 layers at the same time, not only one like it can be done in the filter textfield at the bottom of the snapping-dock.
Here is my code:

```
    def filter_snapping_list(self, reset):
    global filter_List
    if self.dlg==None:
        self.dlg = self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'Snapping and Digitizing Options')
    snapping_mode = self.dlg.findChildren(QToolButton)[2].text()   

    if snapping_mode in ["Advanced", "Erweiterte Konfiguration"]: 

        self.treeview = self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'Snapping and Digitizing Options').findChildren(QTreeView)[0]
        self.treecount = self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'Snapping and Digitizing Options').findChildren(QTreeView)[0].model().rowCount()

        for i in range(self.treecount):
            if reset == False:
                if self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'Snapping and Digitizing Options').findChildren(QTreeView)[0].model().index(i,0).data() in filter_List:
                    self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'Snapping and Digitizing Options').findChildren(QTreeView)[0].setRowHidden(i, QModelIndex(), False)
                else:
                    self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'Snapping and Digitizing Options').findChildren(QTreeView)[0].setRowHidden(i, QModelIndex(), True)
            else:
                self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'Snapping and Digitizing Options').findChildren(QTreeView)[0].setRowHidden(i, QModelIndex(), False)

    else:
        self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error", "Set Snapping-Mode to Advanced!", level=Qgis.Critical, duration=3)



def get_filter_layers(self):
    selectedLayers = self.iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()
    if len(selectedLayers)<1:
        self.iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error", u"No Layers chosen in the TOC !", level=Qgis.Critical, duration=3)
    else:
        global filter_List
        filter_List=[]
        for i in selectedLayers:
            filter_List.append( i.name() )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for update automatically the snap list using only selected layers:

```
snapDock = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'Snapping and Digitizing Options')
treeView = snapDock.findChildren(QTreeView)[0]
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
model = iface.layerTreeView().layerTreeModel()
view = iface.layerTreeView()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

def ShowSelected(item):
    #Hide All
    for layer in canvas.layers():
        node = root.findLayer( layer.id())
        index = model.node2index( node )
        treeView.setRowHidden(index.row(), QModelIndex(), True)
    #Show Selected Only
    for node in view.selectedNodes ():
        index = model.node2index( node )
        treeView.setRowHidden(index.row(), QModelIndex(), False)

view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(ShowSelected)
```

**Note**: *`currentLayerChanged` signal not worked properly in this purpose*

[image]

I hope it helps you

Comment: nice Idea to filter automatically. still there seems no better way to access the layerlist than access it by calling gui-elements like snapDock.findChildren(QTreeView)[0]